# See description in django-rest-framework dropdown?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

How can I see the Subject name in the django-rest-framework dropdown? Now it just says `Subject object`.

[image]

Here are my models:

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='subjects')
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.name)

class Grade(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='grades')

    code = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    requirements = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ranking = models.IntegerField()

    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, related_name='grades', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('subject', 'ranking')
        ordering = ('ranking',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%d: %s' % (self.ranking, self.code)
```

Comment: What is your python version? You can execute `python --version` in a console to find it out.

Comment: By the way, these are your models not your serializers

Comment: Oh, sorry :-) I knew that but thank you for helping and clarifying for other readers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see you have defined `__unicode__` for your model. But perhaps you are using Python 3, in which case for Django models you need to define `__str__` not `__unicode__`

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    ...

    def __str__(self):                # Use this in Python 3
        return '%s' % (self.name)
```

Unrelated, but this is a more succinct return:

```
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```